# Swift 3 detect multiple barcode in 1 line

Tags: ios, barcode

Hi I'm using `swift3` and `AVFoundation` to detect barcode for a bill. My bill have up to 3 barcode in 1 line. How can we combine total barcode into 1 string and make operation stop only after all barcode in the line have been detected and combined into 1 string?

**here is my sample bill**

[image]

There is 3 barcode at the bottom

**here is my AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate function**

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        // This is the delegate'smethod that is called when a code is readed
        for metadata in metadataObjects {
            let readableObject = metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            let code = readableObject.stringValue


            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.delegate?.barcodeReaded(barcode: code!)
            print(code!)
            print(readableObject.type)
        }
    }
```

How can we modify the above to scan all 3 barcode and combine them and notify `Viewcontroller` when all the barcode have been decoded? Any help is much appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do not stop scanning unless 3 barcodes are detected and then combine codes:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    // This is the delegate'smethod that is called when a code is headed

    guard metadataObjects.count == 3 else { return }

    var finalString: String = ""

    for metadata in metadataObjects {
        let readableObject = metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        let code = readableObject.stringValue

        finalString.append(code!)
        print(code!)
        print(readableObject.type)
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.delegate?.barcodeReaded(barcode: finalString)
}
```

Comment: Thanks should be a good solution. But 1 problem is the 1 line can has 1.2 or 3 barcode. We need to read all possible barcode for that line

Comment: You should remove "guard" statement in such a case. But then you will have to distinguish cases when there is only 1 barcode or one of several barcodes is scanned because user has not placed iPhone properly.

Comment: I'm still thinking of using a detection region. For ex a rectange contain the line. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: Do you have possibility to change how bills look like?

Comment: Bill vary from 1 barcode upto 3 barcode but all barcode always allign in 1 line. Normally at top or botton

Comment: You could use something like OpenCV to detect some region. Like a rectangle as you told. But it will be quite a complex solution.

Comment: No I mean to implement scanning region and guide user to place bill so that the barcode line to be completely in that region and detect all possible barcode.